# Is there a way to transform a pandas dataframe to have a particular column's value as a ID or something?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a metrics dataset.  I want to transform the given dataset into something where stringValue == 'IN' will be the ID of the row so that we can filter/extract info based on the stringValue == 'IN'. We will have to group by timeComputed as well.

The following image is of the dataset that we have as an input:

[image]

Our ultimate goal is to find other metrics for the specific country. Here the country is India - 'IN' (there will be different countries in the dataset). I want to find 'col_stats:SUM:Quantity' or other similar metrics for the country 'IN' given the same 'timeComputed'.

I can do it by extracting 'IN' first, then getting the timeComputed and then searching for other metrics with the extracted timeComputed. But this seems like a overdo

I am expecting the resulting dataset similar to following dataset:

| countryCode | timeComputed | metricId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IN | 2021-04-04 | records:COUNT_RECORDS |
| KR | 2022-05-05 | col_stats:SUM:Quantity |

@jezrael I tried the updated solution and it gives me a dataframe as follows:

[image]

So now we need to have a solution where the output dataframe is like where except countryCode every other metricId in that timeComputed should be a column:

| countryCode | timeComputed | reporting:METRICS_COMPUTATION_DURATION | basic:COUNT_COLUMNS | col_stats:COUNT_NULL:EndCustomerAccount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IN | 2023-02-21 13:28:15.705000+00:00 | 2282 | 25 | 75229 |
| IN | 2023-02-21 13:28:38.354000+00:00 | 2765 | 25 | 75229 |

Comment: Can you add input data by expected outoput? E.g. no value `KR` in input data, in row with `IN` is no `records:COUNT_RECORDS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need `partition` and `timeComputed` per `IN` and all rows with match use:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['stringValue'].eq('IN'), ['partition','timeComputed']]

df2 = (df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates())['stringValue','timeComputed','metricId']]
           .rename(columns={'stringValue':'countryCode'}))
```

If need `timeComputed` per `IN` and all rows with match use:

```
s = df.loc[df['stringValue'].eq('IN'), 'timeComputed']

df2 = (df.loc[df['timeComputed'].isin(s),['stringValue','timeComputed','metricId']]
         .rename(columns={'stringValue':'countryCode'}))
```

Comment: Our ultimate goal is to find other metrics for the specific country. Here the country is India - 'IN.'. I want to find 'col_stats:SUM:Quantity' or other similar metrics for the country  'IN' given the same 'timeComputed'. I can do it by extracting 'IN' first, then getting the timeComputed and then searching for other metrics with the extracted timeComputed. But this seems like a overdo.

Comment: @subtle_code - So because in sample data is always same time need all rows? My problem is no match input data by expected ouput. Can you change it?

Comment: @subtle_code - I try change solution.

Comment: I tried your solution and seems like it is a move forward. I have edited the question.

Comment: @subtle_code - Super, so solution working well?

Comment: It is definitely a move forward. But I think now we need to have a solution where the output dataframe will be - where except countryCode every other metricId for same timeComputed will be a column with its stringValue as the column value. I have edited the question further to understand the last bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252071/discussion-between-subtle-code-and-jezrael).